# Customise Android talk-back/accessibility Gestures

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I am working on some online shopping application. In this, we have `Update` `Remove` quantity buttons to manipulate cart quantity.

This works fine in normal flow. but when accessibility is enabled, It got quite complicated as user needs to go back and forth on `plus` and `minus` buttons to adjust the quantity after that user needs to remember to hit `Update` and `Remove` buttons.

I was thinking of a solution if we can override `"SWPE_UP"` and `"SWIPE_DOWN"` gestures after some view clicked so that the `accessibility user` can easily manipulate quantity by `swiping up or down` and once the quantity is set, respective `buttons can be clicked programmatically on double tap`.

I have gone through some articles and searched behavior in similar apps, but couldn't find enough reference material. They won't have similar problems as most apps don't have `Update` or `Remove` buttons.

If anyone can help me to find a solution or provide some reference material then it would be a great help!!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the view? It's not so clear why you'd need update and remove buttons.